# Second Order Cosine Differential Equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Can one think of a solution to:

$$ \lambda f''(x)=f(x)\cos x$$

s.t. $f(0)=0$ and $f(\frac \pi 2)=0$, $\lambda>0$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solutions are special functions known as the [Mathieu functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathieu_function). The more general Mathieu equation is:
$$f''(y)+(a-2q\cos(2y))f(y)=0$$
So in your case $a=0,\ q=1/2\lambda, \ x = y/2$, and the solution is:
$$C_1 \text{MathieuCos}(0,\ 2/\lambda,\ x/2) + C_2 
\text{MathieuSin}(0,\ 2/\lambda,\ x/2)$$
If $y$ is very very small you can approximate $\cos(y)\sim 1$, and get the usual harmonic solutions. This leads to their computation as a Fourier series, an example of which can be found [here](http://www.elsevierdirect.com/companions/9780123846549/Chap_Mathieu.pdf).

Comment: Thanks!! I understand it cannot be expressed in a closed form, but can it be expressed as an integral or sum?

Comment: @TroyMcClure - not really, the're notoriously difficult to express. A Fourier Series exists, but I don't know about a closed form expression for a power series.You can search here for more, but there's not very much:
http://dlmf.nist.gov/28